# How to click on an exact row on wintable with codedui?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I want to click on an exact row in a WinTable where my criteria meets but couldnt succeed so far. I can search criteria for an exact row but I can not get total number of rows so that I would make a loop for all rows. I tried collection and table.Rows.Count,but  both brings nothing to me. Can someone help me on this ?

```
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinTable uIG1Table = this.UIProMANAGEWindow.UIDefinitionsWindow.UIG1Window.UIG1Table;
        WinRow dataGridrow = uIG1Table.GetRow(0);
        #endregion

        UITestControlCollection rows = uIG1Table.Rows;

        // MessageBox.Show(rows[5].RowIndex.ToString());

        foreach (WinRow row in uIG1Table.Rows)

        {

            foreach (WinCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.Value.ToString() == "E81")
                    Mouse.Click(cell, new Point(5, 0));
            }
        }
```

and this is the code with for loop

```
            int rows = uIG1Table.Rows.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            foreach (WinCell cell in dataGridrow.Cells)
            {
                if (cell.Value.ToString() == "E81")
                    Mouse.Click(cell, new Point(5, 0));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing a `GetChildren()` on a row, you will notice that the first child is of type `RowHeader`. A user typically clicks the row header to select the row.

Following code will iterate all the rows in a `DataGridView` and click the row header, effectively selecting the row:

```
UITestControlCollection rows = YourUIMapTable.Rows;

foreach (UITestControl row in rows)
{
    UITestControl rowHeader = row.GetChildren().Single(child => child.ControlType == ControlType.RowHeader);
    Mouse.Click(rowHeader);
}
```

If you want to select a specific row, you can do something like this:

```
Mouse.Click(YourUIMapTable.Rows[putIndexNumberHere].GetChildren().Single(child => child.ControlType == ControlType.RowHeader));
```

The sample code above is based on the program I wrote in my answer to this question:
[How to get cell color information of a WinCell with codedui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630264/how-to-get-cell-color-information-of-a-wincell-with-codedui)

Comment: Where does putIndexNumberHere comes from ? I do not know index number, thats the issue. I want to loop and look for a spefici cell value for each row in order to find the row I am looking for.

Comment: Your solution does not work for me. As I mentioned in my post --> (I tried collection and table.Rows.Count,but both brings nothing to me), I cant not get rows. I tried your code and UITestControlCollection rows is still empty, so it never falls into foreach.

Comment: That's strange... One possibility is that the WinTable got loaded into your UIMap before it had rows? You can force your test to reload the WinTable. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848757/how-to-refresh-uimap-object-in-codedui) Q&A for this. Also double check if your search properties select the correct control. Maybe re-add the control to your UIMap could work?

Comment: Also, once you are able to get that row collection, you will be able to get the correct index number. "putIndexNumberHere" is not a variable, it's just placeholder I put there to indicate you can put a index number for a row between the square brackets.

Comment: I dont think WinTable is not loaded yet, I also run it when table is already open. Maybe bcos its written devexpress ? I see devexpress exist in my references but I am not sure if its used.

Comment: That piece of information is not unimportant, because 3rd party controls are in fact custom controls. You will only be getting coded ui test to work if the 3rd party supports it. DevExpress does support coded ui tests, but against a price. You need to have a universal subscription to be able to download their CUIT extension.

Comment: I have licence but not sure it is universal bt I have devexpress license, also downloded universal trial. When I took record I do not see code as written in their Devexpress extension tutorial page, I still see normal Wintable records, so I think tables are working without the extension. I see in documents that Devexpress Extension just provides more functionality, just as drag and drop columns.